# Build a Facebook OAuth login flow for a native application using JFXPanel

Tags: java, swing, javafx

This is probably a trivial question, but I'm very new to Swing and JavaFX.

I'm trying to build a FB OAuth login form for a almost-completely batch application. I know that I've to open a webview to get a 'code' to be then exchanged with a 'token'. To do that, I want to use a JFXPanel as a barely trivial internal web browser using WebEngine.

Mine is a simple data processing batch job with does the hard work in the main thread only. The code must be embedded into another code where I don't have control of threads other than the main one. Keeping it simple, let's say I must call the WebView with this trivial main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ComponentBrowser browser = new ComponentBrowser();
                browser.setVisible(true);
                browser.loadURL("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html");
           }    


       });
    }
```

ComponentBrowser is defined [here](https://github.com/theclue/talend-components-collection/blob/master/facebook/tFacebookOAuth/src/main/java/org/gabrielebaldassarre/facebook/ComponentBrowser.java).

I need the WebView to be synchronous and this is the optimal flow:

- The main thread goes sleeping
- The user navigates the WebView until he gets the confirmation code
- The code is pushed back to the main thread in some way
- The main thread resumes operation

What I'm missing is how to get back to the caller the content of the response (which has only the word 'Success' in the body) and the url after the redirection (which has the 'code' querystring parameter). Then, the caller should gracefully close the window.

The problem is that I have *no* control over the main thread aside that sleeping/resuming it. The same is for the class with main() code: this code is auto-generated by the data processing platform I must embed my code into. So I've no way to modify that part of the code outside the main() itself (adding methods or listeners to the class it's not possible, but I *can* add statements to the main() code itself)

That's why my communications between the JavaFX and the batch code must be as simple as possible, even trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a listener with the web engine's load worker's state property:

```
engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
    if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
        // document is successfully loaded
    }
});
```

This will be notified when the response is received from the server.

To retrieve the content, you can use `WebEngine.getDocument()`, which returns an [`org.w3c.dom.Document`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html?is-external=true) object. The dom API is a little unwieldy (imo), but I think in your case all you will need is

```
String content = engine.getDocument().getDocumentElement().getTextContent();
```

which you can then check to see if it is `"Success"`.

The threading part gets tricky. If I understand correctly, you are basically running an application here that is almost entirely non-GUI, but you just need a little UI to validate login at startup, then want to return to the main thread and execute the code.

If this were entirely Swing (for the login validation), I would approach this as follows:

From the main thread, call `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)` and pass in a `Runnable` that shows a modal dialog. `invokeAndWait` will block execution of the main thread until the `Runnable` (executed on the AWT thread) completes. By using a modal dialog, you block execution of code until the dialog is dismissed, so now the `Runnable` will not complete until the dialog is dismissed, and consequently the main thread will block until the dialog is dismissed. So now all you need is to arrange to dismiss the dialog when login is validated.

This is made a little more complex by placing a `JFXPanel` in the Swing dialog. You now need to pass off any code modifying the JavaFX components to the JavaFX Application Thread, using `Platform.runLater(...)` and if you change any Swing components (such as closing the dialog), you need to hand that back to the AWT event thread using `SwingUtilities.runLater(...)`.

So here's a quick demo of this in action. I just used a button here, that when pressed loaded "Success" into the web view. Obviously you can replace that by loading the real login screen.

```
import java.awt.Window;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;


public class WaitingForLogin {

    public WaitingForLogin() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Showing window...");

        // Run initAndShowUI() on AWT event thread. Block until that is complete:
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> initAndShowUI());

        System.out.println("Now running application");
        for (int i=1; i <=10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Counting: "+i);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }

    public void initAndShowUI() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog((Window)null);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        Platform.runLater(() -> initJFX(jfxPanel, dialog));
        dialog.add(jfxPanel);
        dialog.setSize(400, 400);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Since the dialog is modal, this will block execution (of the AWT event thread)
        // until the dialog is closed:
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initJFX(JFXPanel jfxPanel, Window dialog) {

        // Create a web view:
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

        // Check for a new document being loaded. If the document just contains the 
        // text "Success", then close the dialog (unblocking all threads waiting for it...)
        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState, newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                Document doc = engine.getDocument();
                if ("Success".equals(doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent())) {
                    // Close dialog: this must be done on the AWT event thread
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> dialog.dispose());
                }
            }
        });

        // Just for testing
        // simulate login with simple button:

        Button button = new Button("Login");
        button.setOnAction(event -> engine.loadContent("Success", "text/plain"));
        HBox controls = new HBox(button);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(webView, null, null, controls, null)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new WaitingForLogin();

    }

}
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer. "Worker" actually gives an error of cannot be resolved as a variable. Said that, I don't know how to communicate to the Swing thread I run from the main one

Comment: For `Worker` you are just missing the import: `javafx.concurrent.Worker`.

Comment: tnx for the prompt reply. Btw here's the code I'm developed so far: https://github.com/theclue/talend-components-collection/blob/master/facebook/tFacebookOAuth/src/main/java/org/gabrielebaldassarre/facebook/ComponentBrowser.java

Comment: Tnx again for your help. Unfortunately the getTextContent is always null, actually...

Comment: You might need to experiment with the dom API a bit. Try `engine.getDocument().getDocumentElement().getTextContent();`, for example.

Comment: ah ok, we land in the dom context...so ok I will keep experimenting. Btw I'm still stucked with the threading stuff. This because I really don't have a GUI to play with. Mine is just a data processing batch job I have to embed into another piece of code. It lies in the main() thread only. This lonely thread must simply wait for the confirmation code from the (synchronous) WebView, get the code and go ahead. Everything else is out of my control (I'll update the question with those info)

Comment: added lot of details on the question

Comment: great! very elegant and working like a charm! Just had to clean-up the lamba expressions (I'm compiling against Java 7). I've still to understand all those threading tricks, but I'll. Tnx for all your support!